# bootstrap buttons coming out too small

Tags: html, web, button, bootstrap-4

hey guys i'm a newbie to web development and i have this little problem with bootstrap that i couldn't solve, it's two buttons that i put in the end of the page and they come out so small with the value attribute not showing, if anyone could help it'd be awesome

**CODE**

```
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Fiche recapitulatif</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Vous êtes:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['nom'].' '.$_SESSION['prenom']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Vous avez:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['age']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Votre num de telephone:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['tel']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Votre email:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Vous êtes en:</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['fil'];
      if ($_SESSION['année']=='1ére') {
        echo "1";
      }elseif ($_SESSION['année']=='2éme') {
        echo "2";
      }elseif ($_SESSION['année']=='3éme') {
        echo "3";
      }
      ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Vous suivez cette année:</strong>   <?php
      echo '<ol>';
      foreach ($_SESSION['module'] as $element) {
        echo '<li>'.$element.'</li>';
      }
      echo "</ol>";
      ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p ><strong>Vous avez réalisé</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['projets']; ?> projets cette année.</p>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" value="Modifier">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="val" value="Valider">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Check out this site (especially the button sizes) [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp)

Comment: i tried using the large size, the buttons come out a little bigger not the size of large buttons and still the value attribute not showing

Comment: i also wrapped them in a row and nothing happens

Comment: hmmm. Could be something with your CSS. Also, you can try and make them inputs. <input class="btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"></input>. Also, you didn't close your button tags.

Comment: yess that was the problem, all i had to do is close my button tags, but i was too blind to see it, thank you so much for the quick response !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to close the button tags (as per my comment).